# Sublime Text regex range

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

What an equivalent to JS regex `/[^0-9\.]/g` could I use in Sublime Text search and replace?

---

**upd:**

I want to replace `array(9.49),` with `9.49,`.

I found a solution:

find: `array\((\d.+)\)(,)`

and replace: `\1\2`

Anyway, I want to know how to use ranges in Sublime to use an equivalent to JS regex `/[^0-9\.]/g` instead of `\d.+`.

Comment: @Ameoo updated with an example

Comment: `\d.+` is completely different from `[^0-9.]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the delimiters (slashes); the global modifier `g` is implicit anyway, and the backslash is unnecessary in either case:

```
[^0-9.]
```

should do.

**EDIT:**

Your edited question now appears to be looking for something completely different:

You want to search for

```
array\(([\d.]+)\),   // or array\(([0-9.]+)\),
```

and replace with

```
\1,
```

Comment: If I use `array\(([^0-9.])\)(,)` instead of `array\((\d.+)\)(,)`, it doesn't work.

Comment: That's because the two regexes are not remotely related to each other. `\d.+` matches one digit, followed by one or more arbitrary characters. `[^0-9.]` matches one character that's neither a digit nor a dot.